# Elasticsearch shards stuck in UNASSIGNED state after REPLICA_ADDED

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi recently i have added a new node in cluster, earlier we were using only one node. Out of these two node one is master another is dataNode.

And we have replication factor 1. Out of three indices, two indices replicated properly, and shards moved to another node.
But there is one index for which all secondary shards stucked in UNASSIGNED state and reason is REPLICA_ADDED.

I tried everything but didn't worked. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version (I think 5.0 or newer), the [Cluster Allocation Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-allocation-explain.html) is your friend. It will show you exactly why a shard is not being allocated.

> Out of these two node one is master another is dataNode.

I assume both nodes are data and master eligible nodes (which are the default settings), right? Also be sure to set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` to the correct value or you are risking split brains in your cluster; see the docs for [the master election process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#master-election). Generally, you'll want 3 master eligible nodes for a HA setup.